# Getting Error when trying to knit in R Markdown using R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am getting this error when trying to knit HTML Document in R Studio using R Markdown:
[image]

Comment: There is no way for us to assist without seeing the code that generates the error.  It will appear at or about line 9.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. Minimal, complete, verifiable example(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: ---
title: "Untitled"
author: "som"
date: "October 19, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
line 9 is Knitr::opts_chunk$.....

Comment: ---
title: "Untitled"
author: "som"
date: "October 19, 2016"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup,include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```


```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Comment: above is the code, can some one please give me a solution for this please, code looks fine , but I am getting the Evaluate_Call Errror

Comment: @SomeshwarRao Please put the code in your question, i.e. edit your question!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your packages are up to date.

Tools -> Check for Package Updates...

I had this problem, and had a bunch of package updates waiting. This fixed it for me.

Comment: It can be surprising how many times knitr FAQ 1 can help: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md :)